# How do I call the MySQL basedir within php?

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

Is it possible for php to call the mysqli "basedir"?

In my my.ini file I have this line:
basedir="c:/wamp64/bin/mysql/mysql5.7.14"

And in php I can type out the whole path as above and it works nicely. Can php call this variable in the same sort of way you can call $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']?

I have looked through the mysqli class commands but nothing seems to return the basedir.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please be careful when writing your php code to use server-local variables like `@@basedir`. Almost all web apps (in php or other languages) will run with the php code on one machine and the MySQL server on a different one. So the `@@basedir` value won't mean much on the machine running php.

Comment: Thats a good point O. Jones. In this case it is my own local server. The 'select @@basedir' works a treat, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You clould query direc to to to the DB with

```
 select @@basedir
```

or

```
select @@basedir basedir;
```